# How to create a direct access to a program using the terminal

Tags: bash

I recently installed Chimera (https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/) in my computer (Ubuntu 20.04), in /home/roy/chimera (later I will ask how to change the programs directory), so I access the program with the commands:

```
cd chimera
cd bin
 ./chimera
```

Can I create a script called `chimera` that executes the program? So just typing the scripts name in `home/roy` I will access the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Add the directory to your execution path. For the current shell, type `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/chimera/bin` on the command line. Or to set the path for future shell sessions, put this line in a profile or RC file; for example if your shell is Bash, add it to the end of `/home/roy/.bashrc`.

Option 2: Create an alias `alias chimera=/home/roy/chimera/bin/chimera`. Either on the command line for the current session, or add that line to one of the profiles or RC files as in option 2. In the case of Bash, you can also add it to `/home/roy/.bash_aliases`, or create that file if it does not exist.

Option 3: Create a symbolic link in a directory that is already in your path. To see the path, type `echo $PATH`. If the path contains, for example, /usr/local/bin, you could add that link like this: `ln -s /home/roy/chimera/bin/chimera /usr/local/bin`. I would not modify directories like `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, as their content is managed by the APT package management system (though it is unlikely to cause harm).

I don't know which of the three option is better, and I am sure there are other options.

Comment: Regarding your question about changing directories, the [installation instructions](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/data/downloads/1.15/linux_x86_64.html) say "The chimera installer will optionally put a symbolic link to the chimera application on your path". So, this could have been done automatically. The instructions then mention my option 3 in case the link was not created as part of the installation.